# open new page in new window in gridview buttonfield

Tags: asp.net

i have gridview in my asp.net page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CssClass="Gridview"
                    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField Text="VIEW" ButtonType="link" CommandName="view" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I want to open new page in new window.

for that i have used below code.(this code is not working !- please check if any error)

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("view"))
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[index];
        String id= gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
        string url = "~/Mypage.aspx?myid=" + id;
        Response.Write("<script>window.open( 'www.google.com' , '-blank' );</script>");
    }
}
```

**I am  binding data at runtime in GRIDVIEW**
please  keep this in mind.

so that i can not use hyperlink field.

Suggest me ways to open new page in new window using coding in gridview.

Answer (score 3):

Better late then never... I had the same problem myself so I post here for other coders to maybe get help.

First I used linkbutton rather than buttonfield...

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="viewLink" runat="server" CommandName="Select"  >
       <img class="pdficon" src="../Pictures/pdf_icon.png" />
   </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

(had a picture to click for opening a document in new window, just ignore that)

My gridview had following code... (name on gridview documentGridView)

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="openLinkClick"
DataKeyNames="docfolder"
```

And in my codebehind I passed the link to the new page as a parameter when i requested a new "default" page

```
protected void openLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //lots of code for constructing link, the important thing is SelectedDataKey
    string docId = documentsGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();    
    //passing link as parameter when opening a new default page with given
    //dimensions for new window
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "", "window.open('Document.aspx?param1=" + link + "','Graph','height=900,width=1100');", true);
    //refresh page
    Page_Load(this, null);
}
```

Finally in Page_Load of the Document.aspx I had following code for fetching link and open my file, in your cause it should be possible to fetch link and make a redirect.

```
public partial class Document : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open pdf in browser
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        //get the parameter containing the adress for the file
        string link = Request.QueryString["param1"];
        //open the file
        Response.WriteFile(link);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Maybe not the prittiest solution but one way to work around blank pages open on client side and not server side.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code from

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open( 'www.google.com' , '-blank' );</script>");
```

to

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Message", "window.open('www.google.com','_blank');", true);
```